# Automator / Apple Script to turn on Do Not Disturb while Screen Share

Tags: automator

Didn't manage to find any online. I am using Mac OS 11.5 Big Sur. I would like to have "Do Not Disturb" turned on (no notifications) whenever I am screen sharing (Google Meet, etc.). Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Muzzle](https://muzzleapp.com/) is an app that does it automatically for you.

> a simple mac app to silence embarrassing notifications while screensharing

> Automatically turn on Do Not Disturb when screensharing starts. Works with almost everything, including:
>
> - Slack
> - Join Me
> - Google Hangouts
> - Zoom
> - BlueJeans

Minimum system requirements: macOS Mojave and later.